# Python compare first element of all rows?

Tags: python, csv

I don't know how to do this.

I have a cvs file that has this info:

```
1 | A | B
1 | C | D
2 | E | F
3 | G |H
3 | I | J
```

My list is pipe separated not comma.
What I am trying to do is: 'if first element of the column of the cvs is the same, then merge the contents".

Desired output:

```
    <h1>1</h1>
    <h2>A</h2>
    B
    <h2>C</h2>
    D
    <h1>2</h1>
    <h2>E</h2>
    F
    <h1>3</h1>
    <h2>G</h2>
    H
    <h2>I</h2>
    J
```

My code

```
for row in csv_reader:    

for each group of rows where the first element is the same (in this case "1")
    print ='    <h1>row[0]</h1>
            <h2>row[1]</h2>
            row[2]
            <h2>C (this is from second row)</h2>
            D (this is from second row)
```

Comment: This is a  non well defined csv result. What did you try? where is your porblem? do you know how to read a csv from file? do you know how to handle lists of rows/columns/data? SO does not code for you, we help you fix your code - where is it? [mre]

Comment: If you don't know where to start, try thinking about how you would do it if you had to do it by hand. If you open up the csv in Excel and need to do this, how would you go about it? Can you turn that approach into some clear steps you can perform one after the other? After that, it's just about turning those steps into Python code - and if you have specific problems with that, those would be good to ask about on StackOverflow. Don't spend time on making the question look pretty, share csv data as csv data and share Python code as Python code that people can run.

Comment: @Grismar I updated the code now.

Comment: Is it actually pipe-separated, or is it a comma-separated file?

Comment: @James pipe separated

Comment: Your code does nothing  - it does not even adhere to python, it is missing imports. Currently WE would have to write the complete program for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that the file `data.csv` looks like this:

```
1 | A | B
1 | C | D
2 | E | F
3 | G |H
3 | I | J
```

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and `collections.defaultdict`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, sep='|')

object_col_names = data.select_dtypes('O').columns
data[object_col_names] = data[object_col_names].apply(
    lambda x: x.str.strip()
)

d = defaultdict(list)
for i in data.index:
    d[data[0].loc[i]].extend(data[[1, 2]].loc[i].tolist())

for i in sorted(d.keys()):
    print(f'<h1>{i}</h1>')
    for j, k in enumerate(d[i]):
        if j % 2 == 0:
            print(f'<h2>{k}</h2>')
        else:
            print(k)
```

Output:

```
<h1>1</h1>
<h2>A</h2>
B
<h2>C</h2>
D
<h1>2</h1>
<h2>E</h2>
F
<h1>3</h1>
<h2>G</h2>
H
<h2>I</h2>
J
```

Comment: Hi @MarkusHam, I've just changed the code, now it should be more general and it should properly achieve what you want. Let me know in case you have any further questions or doubts.

Comment: I'm glad :)
Have a beautiful day!